# PHP add up two time variables

Tags: php, mysql

In my PHP application I want to calculate the sum of two time variables. I am looking for something like this example.

```
$time1 = 15:20:00;
$time2 = 00:30:00;
$time = $time1+$time2;
```

Comment: How have you tried to do this?

Comment: Do you have some examples of what your results should look like?

Comment: DateTime and DateInterval classes. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: The result should added current time + a time variable which i am taking from DB say $tim2

Comment: date and times cant be added directly, checkout Sammaye answer, you have to convert them to strings first and then add.

Comment: This may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37893459/3164430 I fany queries please comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is most likely to use strtotime to convert them to timestamps and then do the adding together:

`$o = strtotime($time1)+strtotime($time2);`

If I remember right `strtotime` does support this format.

Otherwise you will need to filter it out yourself.

Comment: The result should added current time + a time variable which i am taking from DB say $tim2

Comment: $time = date("H:i:s")+strtotime($mysql_time); you mean this way..?

Comment: @Rakesh No, time() returns a timestamp of the current time so you wanna use time()

Comment: @Rakesh Wait what do you mean? What part of the current time do you wanna add? the hour:sec:minute? try: `strtotime(date('H:i:s'))+strtotime($mysql_time)`

Comment: @Rakesh Your looking for interval not to add the two together. Look at feela's answer below.

Comment: @cha what is your code, you might find that the strtotime is not correctly functioning, but this is summing two integers, i.e. 1+1 as such this code cannot really fail without PHPs core math library failing

Comment: @Sammaye Yes. This is summing two integers. But finally returned wrong answer. I created a simple function. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

If the answer you expect is `15:50:00` and you want to use `strtotime` and `date` functions, you need to subtract the seconds `$time1` and `$time2` share when you transform them to unix timestamps:

```
$time1 = '15:20:00';
$time2 = '00:30:00';
$time = strtotime($time1) + strtotime($time2) - strtotime('00:00:00');
$time = date('H:i:s', $time);
```

Comment: This is great and simple but it would be more relevant if you can provide further explanations about subtracting that 0 value time.

Answer (score 4):

Following answer does not return correct value. It is summing integers but not returned correct time.

$o = strtotime($time1)+strtotime($time2);

I created a function to get calculated time as follows.

```
public function addTwoTimes($time1 = "00:00:00", $time2 = "00:00:00"){
        $time2_arr = [];
        $time1 = $time1;
        $time2_arr = explode(":", $time2);
        //Hour
        if(isset($time2_arr[0]) && $time2_arr[0] != ""){
            $time1 = $time1." +".$time2_arr[0]." hours";
            $time1 = date("H:i:s", strtotime($time1));
        }
        //Minutes
        if(isset($time2_arr[1]) && $time2_arr[1] != ""){
            $time1 = $time1." +".$time2_arr[1]." minutes";
            $time1 = date("H:i:s", strtotime($time1));
        }
        //Seconds
        if(isset($time2_arr[2]) && $time2_arr[2] != ""){
            $time1 = $time1." +".$time2_arr[2]." seconds";
            $time1 = date("H:i:s", strtotime($time1));
        }

        return date("H:i:s", strtotime($time1));
    }
```

Comment: Yeah your scenario was a bit more complex and required more use of strototime

Comment: Yes. That's true. We can use this kind of solution until find a better approach to solve that

Answer (score 2):

You could use the PHP 5.3 [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/class.dateinterval.php):

```
$timeInterval = DateInterval::createFromDateString( '15 hours + 20 minutes' );
$timeInterval2 = DateInterval::createFromDateString( '30 minutes' );

foreach( str_split( 'ymdhis' ) as $prop )
{
    $timeInterval->$prop += $timeInterval2->$prop;
}
var_dump( $timeInterval->format( '%H:%i:%s' ) );
```

(How to add to DateInterval objects was explained here: [How we can add two date intervals in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556731/how-we-can-add-two-date-intervals-in-php))

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Sammaye's answer did't work out for me.

I needed to start the time I wanted to add with the start of the UNIX timestamp. This way, `strtotime` returns the seconds that need to be added to the first time.

```
$time1 = "15:20:00";
$time2 = "1970-01-01 00:30:00";
$time = strtotime($time1) + (strtotime($time2) + 3600);
echo $time . "<br />";
echo date("H:i:s", $time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to consult the mystic docs https://www.php.net/strtotime for additional things you can input into your functions :)

```
$today = time();
$tommorrow = strtotime("+1 days", $today);
$day_after_tomorrow = strtotime("+1 days", $tomorrow);
```

Answer (score -1):

**Code:**

```
$time1 = '15:20:00';
$time2 = '00:30:00';
$time = strtotime($time1)+strtotime($time2);
$sumtime = date("H:i:s",$time);
```

Comment: Hi sumesh how to add current time + $time2 ..?

Comment: This one should return `15:50:00` but returns `09:21:44`