# Adding two time values in php

Tags: php

```
    $test=strtotime("06:30:00")+strtotime("03:00:00");

    echo gmdate("H:i:s", $test);
```

This gives the wrong answer ( 23:01:44 ).

```
    $test=strtotime("06:30:00")-strtotime("03:00:00");

    echo gmdate("H:i:s", $test);
```

while subtracting same code gives me the right answer( 03:30:00 ).

Comment: You cannot add/subtract points in time. Add/subtract `TimeSpan`s instead. Or calc back to seconds since epoch en add/subtract those.

Comment: can you give me an example with code in php?

Comment: you will have to tell what you want. The code you provided is nonsense. `strtotime` will give you a point in (absolute) time. You cannot add another absolute timestamp to that. If you are working with time durations, `strtotime` is the wrong tool.

Comment: I am sorry but i am a beginner,
Actually I have a loop in my code which give time durations (in hour and minutes) and i want to calculate the total of that.

Comment: I think my answer may help you Here is the Solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37893459/3164430

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this:

```
<?
echo date("H:i:s", strtotime("06:30:00 + 3 hour"));
echo date("H:i:s", strtotime("06:30:00 - 3 hour"));
?>
```

Comment: Thank You... This is what i needed, and i got it from your answer. :)
echo date("H:i:s", strtotime("06:30:00 - 3 hour 30 minutes"));

Comment: Hope you got my back all the time.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong. If you'll act like in 1-st sample, you'll sum two timestamps as they are (i.e. starting from 0) - so you'll count previous time twice. If you are subtracting them, however, you're getting 'expected' result because each operand's previous period eliminates another.

But that's not how it's supposed to work. You should use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) API to work with dates and periods in PHP.

Comment: I am sorry but i am a beginner, Actually I have a loop in my code which give time durations (in hour and minutes) and i want to calculate the total of that.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem, and wrote a small function to convert times (formatted in a variety of ways) to seconds.  It's obviously then trivial to add the seconds together.

```
function getSeconds($s) {
    $s = str_replace('h',':',$s);
    $s = str_replace(',','.',$s);

    $a = explode(':',$s);
    $n = count($a);

    if ($n==1)
        return $a[0]; //just seconds

    if ($n==2)
        return $a[1] + 60 * $a[0]; //minutes and seconds

    if ($n==3)
        return $a[2] + 60 * $a[1] + 3600 * $a[0]; //hours minutes and seconds
}
```

Works for the following formats:

```
 12
 12.34
 12:34 (will assume mm:ss in this format)
 12:34.56
 12:34,56
 12:34:56.78
 12h34:56,78
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $date1 = strtotime('2012-05-01 12:00:00');
 $date2 = time();
 $subTime = $date1 - $date2;
 $y = ($subTime/(60*60*24*365));
 $d = ($subTime/(60*60*24))%365;
 $h = ($subTime/(60*60))%24;
 $m = ($subTime/60)%60;

 echo "Difference between ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date1)." and ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date2)." is:\n";
 echo $y." years\n";
 echo $d." days\n";
 echo $h." hours\n";
 echo $m." minutes\n";
```