# Get total amount of hours from 2 variables

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
$time = "20:58:05";
$time2 = "10:40:00";

$secs = strtotime($time2)-strtotime("00:00:00");
$result = date("H:i:s",strtotime($time)+$secs);
echo $result;
```

The output of the above code is - `07:38:05`

i want it to display like this - `31:38:05`. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Are you open to using other libraries, like Carbon?

Comment: If you want to get more than 24 hours, you need to add dates as well. PHP can't know if the time is on another date or not unless you tell it to. And you can't use `date()` for this since that's for generating proper _date and time_, while you're looking for a _diff_.

Comment: You should use the `DateInterval` class, not timestamps.

Comment: i got that code from here - [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557076/adding-two-time-values-of-similar-formats-using-php).. the problem is when the total reaches 24, it goes back to 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert both times to seconds, add them, and then calculate the hours, minutes, and seconds yourself.

```
$time = "20:58:05";
$time2 = "10:40:00";

$secs = strtotime($time)-strtotime("00:00:00");
$secs2 = strtotime($time2)-strtotime("00:00:00");
$total = $secs + $secs2;
$hours = floor($total/3600);
$mins = floor(($total % 3600) / 60);
$secs = $total % 60;
echo sprintf("%d:%02d:%02d", $hours, $mins, $secs);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Barmar works when adding hours that are below 24:00:00, but when you add 2 variable with each variable exceeds 24:00:00 it gives a wrong output. For example:

```
$time = "20:58:05";
$time2 = "30:40:00";

$secs = strtotime($time)-strtotime("00:00:00");
$secs2 = strtotime($time2)-strtotime("00:00:00");
$total = $secs + $secs2;
$hours = floor($total/3600);
$mins = floor(($total % 3600) / 60);
$secs = $total % 60;
echo sprintf("%d:%02d:%02d", $hours, $mins, $secs);
```

output of the above code: `-431348:-2:-55`

Here is a code that works even if the data of the variables exceeds 24:00:00:

```
  function sum_the_time($time1, $time2) {
  $times = array($time1, $time2);
  $seconds = 0;
  foreach ($times as $time)
  {
    list($hour,$minute,$second) = explode(':', $time);
    $seconds += $hour*3600;
    $seconds += $minute*60;
    $seconds += $second;
  }
  $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
  $seconds -= $hours*3600;
  $minutes  = floor($seconds/60);
  $seconds -= $minutes*60;
  if($seconds < 9)
  {
  $seconds = "0".$seconds;
  }
  if($minutes < 9)
  {
  $minutes = "0".$minutes;
  }
    if($hours < 9)
  {
  $hours = "0".$hours;
  }
  return "{$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}";
}
```

i found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557076/adding-two-time-values-of-similar-formats-using-php/10557194)